# How can I make org-pomodoro silence?

Tags: org-mode

I am using [org-pomodoro](https://github.com/marcinkoziej/org-pomodoro), in order to start a pomodoro for the task at point or select one of the last tasks that you clocked time for.

When pomodoro completed it plays a alert sound. I was wondering is it possible to use `org-pomodoro` in complete silent mode, where alert sounds would be suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short examination of the sources from the link you provide finds [this](https://github.com/marcinkoziej/org-pomodoro/blob/master/org-pomodoro.el#L63):

```el
(defcustom org-pomodoro-play-sounds t
  "Determines whether sounds are played or not."
  :group 'org-pomodoro
  :type 'boolean)
```

So customize `org-pomodoro-play-sounds` to nil and see if that does what you want.